# Function is not a function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have some problems with AngularJS, I try to add class to scroll in parallax but I got error

> addTest is not a function

This is scrollTest directive

```
   testmodule.directive('scrollTest', function($window) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.spies = [];
    return this.addTest = function(testObj) {
      return $scope.spies.push(testObj);
    };
  },
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    $('body').addClass('viewing-page-0');
    return $($window).scroll(function() {
      var highlightTest, pos, test, testElem, _i, _len, _ref;
      highlightTest = null;
      _ref = scope.spies;
      for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        test = _ref[_i];
        test.out();
        testElem = elem.find('#' + test.id);
        if ((testElem != null) && testElem.length !== 0) {
          if ((pos = testElem.offset().top) - $window.pageYOffset <= 0) {
            test.pos = pos;
            if (highlightTest == null) {
              highlightTest = test;
            }
            if (highlightTest.pos < test.pos) {
              highlightTest = test;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return highlightTest != null ? highlightTest["in"]() : void 0;
    });
  }
};
```

});

Comment: what is `scrollTest`, where is this passed to `link()`?

Comment: do you have `scrollTest` directive present, which has controller with `addTest` method?

Comment: @PankajParkar yes I have

Comment: @Oleg could you add that directive too here?

Comment: @PankajParkar, I try but is too many codes

Comment: @atmd he is using angular `require` option by which he is accessing of controller scope of parent directive..

Comment: my comment was before the code was updated

Comment: @PankajParkar please check now

Comment: @Oleg do change your controller to `controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.spies = [];
    $scope.addTest = function(testObj) {
      return $scope.spies.push(testObj);
    };
  },` pointed method in scope rather than using this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue. There are problems in these lines `return highlightTest != null ? highlightTest["in"]() : void 0;` and `test.out();`. Should be another arguments.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `addTest` on the template then (1) you should add the function to the scope object or (2) use the controllerAs property on the directive.

//1

```
  testmodule.directive('scrollTest', function($window) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.spies = [];
    $scope.addTest = function(testObj) {
      return $scope.spies.push(testObj);
    };
  },
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    $('body').addClass('viewing-page-0');
    return $($window).scroll(function() {
      var highlightTest, pos, test, testElem, _i, _len, _ref;
      highlightTest = null;
      _ref = scope.spies;
      for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        test = _ref[_i];
        test.out();
        testElem = elem.find('#' + test.id);
        if ((testElem != null) && testElem.length !== 0) {
          if ((pos = testElem.offset().top) - $window.pageYOffset <= 0) {
            test.pos = pos;
            if (highlightTest == null) {
              highlightTest = test;
            }
            if (highlightTest.pos < test.pos) {
              highlightTest = test;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return highlightTest != null ? highlightTest["in"]() : void 0;
    });
  }
};
});
```

//2

```
 testmodule.directive('scrollTest', function($window) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  controllerAs: 'ctrl',
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.spies = [];
    this.addTest = function(testObj) {
      return $scope.spies.push(testObj);
    };
  },
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {// Add the controller to the parameter list if you want to use it here
    $('body').addClass('viewing-page-0');
    return $($window).scroll(function() {
      var highlightTest, pos, test, testElem, _i, _len, _ref;
      highlightTest = null;
      _ref = scope.spies;
      for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        test = _ref[_i];
        test.out();
        testElem = elem.find('#' + test.id);
        if ((testElem != null) && testElem.length !== 0) {
          if ((pos = testElem.offset().top) - $window.pageYOffset <= 0) {
            test.pos = pos;
            if (highlightTest == null) {
              highlightTest = test;
            }
            if (highlightTest.pos < test.pos) {
              highlightTest = test;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return highlightTest != null ? highlightTest["in"]() : void 0;
    });
  }
};
});
```

And on the template:

```
<div ng-click="ctlr.addTest()">
```

The controller function is used as a constructor. Then you don't need to return nothing from it.